# Unexpected output in file handling

Tags: c, file, fgets

My input file is this

```
1001
1001
1101
1109
```

I have the following code-

```
char line[4];    
while(fgets(line,5,input)!=NULL)
 {
   printf("%s",line);

 }
```

It gives me the correct output as follows-

```
1001
1001
1101
1109
```

But if I modify my code to this-

```
while(fgets(line,5,input)!=NULL)
 {
   printf("%s",line);
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
     int c=line[i]-'0';
     printf("% d   ",c);     
    }printf("\n");   
 }
```

I get strange answer now-

```
1001 1    0    0    1   

-38   -48    0    1   
1001 1    0    0    1   

-38   -48    0    1   
1101 1    1    0    1   

-38   -48    0    1   
1009 1    0    0    9   

-38   -48    0    9
```

Why is this strange output coming in my second case??

Comment: `while(fgets(line,5,input)!=NULL)` --> `while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),input)!=NULL)`

Comment: Same result as before

Comment: The 1st example does not match the output shown. Where does the new-line come from? Also reading 5 `char`s into an array of 4 `char`s provokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: How is `line` defined for the 2nd example? If same as for the 1st anything could happend, for why: please see my previous comment.

Comment: Ok then if I used `char * line` and use `sizeof(line)` it should have given me correct answer.But doing that gives me `segmentation fault`

Comment: "*it should have given me correct answer.*" from what do you get this idea? `char * line` is just a pointer pointing to nothing. To read 4 characters plus a new-line into a C-"string" you need to provide at least 4+1+1 `char`s. The sixth `char` is to store the `0`-terminator of the C-"string" needed to mark its end.

Answer (score 3):

Your `char` array has 4 elements, while you're trying to put 5 elements [considering the null terminator] into it.

This way, you're accessing out-of-bound memory which produces undefined behaviour.

Also, worthy to mention, `fgets()` reads and stores the *newline*. You need to take care of that yourself.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still the same result,instead of `-38` its `-32` now.But I dont know where these values are coming from

Comment: What did he suggest? @Coder

Comment: Shouldn't it be like (4 chars + 1 newline + 1 null) ?

Comment: Yes increasing size to 6 worked,but why is it so?`null ` should be in the last line only not in any other line

Comment: Ok thanks and one more thing,if I use `char * line` and instead of size `6` I use `sizeof(line)` then why is it giving me segmentation fault

Comment: That's another issue. Point 1. That way, you need to allocate memory to `line` before using it. Point 2. `sizeof()` returns the size of the _data type_, not the amount of memory (_if_) allocated.

Comment: Also why can I use strlen(line) to get length of each line.This is giving me an error

Comment: @Coder if you're using `strlen(line)` to get the length of _valid_ input, line should be null-terminated, without the newline in it. Please let us know the context.

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
int c=line[i]-'0';
```

you are converting only one digit to an int but you want to convert the whole digit string:

```
int c= 0;
char *cp= line;
while (isdigit(*cp)) c= c*10 + *cp++ - '0';
```